# Code does not send what I want repedeately

Tags: python, c++, arduino, raspberry-pi3

I was trying to make a project about NRF24L01+ and connecting it to arduino and raspberry pi. Then, I wrote the code. It did not respond. So, I took it from a website and it worked. However, it was sending the message once. But the code there was written to send it continously. So, I decided to put a serial line in the Arduino code to figure out what I was doing wrong. And as expected, the serial line printed "A" once. But I placed it in a loop! So, do you guys have an idea about what I am doing wrong?

The arduino code is shown below:

```
//These libraries are fully downloaded.
#include<SPI.h>
#include<RF24.h>

// ce, csn pins, connected properly.
RF24 radio(9, 10) ;
//Here, I set up the stuff needed for the Transciever.
void setup(void){
  radio.begin() ;
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MAX) ;
  radio.setChannel(0x76) ;
  radio.openWritingPipe(0xF0F0F0F0E1LL) ;
  radio.enableDynamicPayloads() ;
  radio.powerUp() ;
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
void loop(void){
  const char text[] = "Hello World!" ;
  Serial.println("A");
  radio.write(&text, sizeof(text)) ;
  delay(1000) ;
  //s
 }
```

And the RPI3 code is shown below:

```
#The libraries are downloaded.
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from lib_nrf24 import NRF24
import time
import spidev

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]

radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
radio.begin(0, 17)

radio.setPayloadSize(32)
radio.setChannel(0x76)
radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_1MBPS)
radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)

radio.setAutoAck(True)
radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
radio.enableAckPayload()

radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
radio.printDetails()
radio.startListening()
try:
 while(1):
     # ackPL = [1]
     while not radio.available(0):
         time.sleep(1 / 100)
     receivedMessage = []
     radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
     print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

     print("Translating the receivedMessage into unicode characters")
     string = ""
     for n in receivedMessage:
         # Decode into standard unicode set
         if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
             string += chr(n)
     print("Out received message decodes to: {}".format(string))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

So, do you see any problem in my code? I really need to solve this.
Here is the link where I took them from:
https://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-vPCDxo7hAhUKyaYKHZP9DQ8QFjAKegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fthezanshow.com%2Felectronics-tutorials%2Fraspberry-pi%2Ftutorial-34-35&usg=AOvVaw26oek-_CM80ujzcc_PBk0N

And here is the screenshot of the terminal when I run the code:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S94Z.png)

Comment: It seems likely that radio.write() isn't returning ... I'd take a look at the code of that and check what's going on in that.

Comment: Could you please write which code I should check?

Comment: That would be easy to test. Add another `Serial.println("B");` and see if it executes after the radio write. And after that, I would declare my static variable outside of the loop, memory is scares in Arduino, you don't want to fill it up.
It could also be a power issue, the Arduino is known to hang/crash intermittently if power usage gets fucky. Radio stuff tends to suck juice like crazy. How many amps is your power supply?

Comment: It does not write on the port. Now what should I do?

Comment: Thanks sir, but when I try that, it says that I did not declare what "text" is.

Comment: I have no idea however, I put it on 3v3.

Comment: There is no change sir.

Comment: The output you show in the screenshot shows the decoded message as, "Hello World is awesome", but it looks like the Arduino code is only sending, "Hello World!". Is it possible that you forgot to re-upload the looping code to the Arduino?

Comment: Thanks, everyone. The issue was about power supply and I got rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the RF24 module says that the write function blocks until a successful acknowleding by the reciever: [Description of write function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xlR8.png) so I assume you do not send any acknowledgement back from your RPI. I recommend reading the [documentation](https://nrf24.github.io/RF24/index.html) carefully and choosing one of the other write Methods. Also take a look at the Python documentation of lib_nrf24